# Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=100 "Protocol error"

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am trying to call a service using Alamofire using a .get method.
The request has nothing special no parameters just an Authorization header.

I am going a bit mad here because to request works fine when I run it on postman with the same URL and Authorization token, but when I run my app code with Alamofire it returns this error:

> Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=100 "Protocol error" UserInfo={NSErrorPeerAddressKey={length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes = 0x100201bbd83ad0b10000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=100, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}

I am using:

```
Alamofire.request("https://myserverURL", method: .get, parameters: [:], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: ["Authorization":"myToken"])
        .responseJSON {response in 

    guard response.result.error == nil else { 
       //HERE IS WHERE IS GOING IN WITH THE ERROR
    }
}
```

Any thoughts will be much appreciated or point me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got exact same error as yours in Cocoa with foundation class `URLSession`. After hours debugging the issue lies in the HTTP request body.

You should really try to **dump the HTTP request/response body** to see if there are some malformed fields. For example, `Content-Length` and `Content-Type` are right or missing? In my experience if these required(fundamental) headers are malformed, it **may not work** depending on your OS or other intermediate network accept(e.g. proxy, gateway, server, etc.)

My fault is misplacing function params in the method `URLRequest.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")`, which ends up with a wrong `Content-Type` HTTP field.

However, it works in macOS 10.12 but not 12.11 so **you should makes sure your HTTP Request body is not malformed**.

Hope it helps.

---

Form your sample code, I guess the `encoding: JSONEncoding.default` is wrong. Since **an HTTP GET method has NO body**, a strict/not-robust network component would reject/not understand it.

What your goal is set the `Accept: application/json` in the request header, however it's not required if you're sure the response body type.

Answer (score 10):

I got this error with Apache sending an `upgrade` header. Here is a link to Apache's [bugzilla](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59311) discussion on the issue.

Fixed it by adding `Header unset Upgrade` to host config in Apache.

Comment: i use an elb and had this error on safari.  I tried adding the unset upgrade to the sites .htaccess and it didnt work, then i tried putting the  in the /var/www section of the root httpd.conf and all was good.

Answer (score 4):

This was a tricky one at least for me for an entire day . I figure out at the end how to solve it, it was an HTTP protocol version issue with the server.

We were using IIS to connect to a development API and by default IIS if I remember correctly above 10 use HTTP 2.0 if both the client and the server support it. Also, our server was using an SSL certificate for the development API so I think this was the main issue combined with HTTP 2.0. Disabling the use of HTTP 2.0 for the IIS in the development API fixes the issue.

So my advice is to try to monitor the incoming request to see which kind of protocol is using the request in the server, you can do it with **Charles** or any another HTTP monitor tool.

I hope this helps someone else with the same problem.

Comment: Disabling HTTP 2.0 works for me. In my case I'm using a Load Balancer on AWS using TLS certificate for HTTPs.

Comment: **Charles** was the reason of this error for me. I was uploading files to the server, and it worked only for small files (several kb). Turning off Charles allowed to upload any large file. I don't know the reason.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `["Content-Type": "application/json"`]  to the headers helped.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using some kind of sniffer, try to turn it off. 
Running **Charles** was the reason of this error for me. I was uploading files to the server, and it worked only for small files (several kb). 500kb file leads me to "EOF" failure in Charles, and to your error in xCode. Turning off Charles allowed to upload any large file. I didn't find the exact reason of this yet. 
Charles worked well with the same query via Web, but not with iOS.

Answer (score 3):

I have worked with apache server, I have fixed issue by adding `Upgrade` key in header.

**Example:**

```
let headers = ["Upgrade":"h2,h2c", "Content-Type":"application/json"]
```

Hope it will help other.

Answer (score 2):

try to replace this parameters: [:] with parameters: nil in your request. Strangely it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue fixed it by replacing  **Authorization** feild value to nil instead of  ""

```
[request setValue: @"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

changed it to this

```
[request setValue: nil forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, you must add an entry to ignore the header containing "Upgrade" as shown in this solution: https://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=55803
And
https://serverfault.com/questions/937253/https-doesnt-work-with-safari

In some cases it was only necessary to add a line in htaccess

```
Header unset Upgrade
```

I hope I helped you

Answer (score 0):

In my case there were several F5 balancers in the test network. One of the F5 servers were validating the request incorrectly in such a way that json's objects containing @ or / were considered malformed. The issue was hard to detect because many times it was working for me, but few times it was not - exactly according to the specific misconfigured F5 server that my client app was communicating with.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I used **Google Places API**, then I figured it out the problem was HTTP body, I set my HTTP body to nil and the problem solved

Answer (score 0):

> After spending hours the fix was adding "Upgrade" field in header.

```
let headerFields = ["Upgrade":"h2,h2c","Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue and resolved it by renaming the authentication header from `firebase_token` to `auth`.

I'm building both the backend and the frontend, so it's a reasonable solution.

It looks like the Nginx proxy was cutting off all the unknown headers.