# Swift Authorization Header over SSL

Tags: ios, swift, ssl

I have updated an API to force SSL.  Now my swift/ios application fails for any call that includes an Authorization header.  Only logging in and an insecure api call as a test works.

If I disable the SSL, everything works again.

I have also verified the server works correctly with fiddler.

I feel like I'm missing something simple, but my searches for answers are currently futile.

I should add in the HTTPURLResponse that data is nil, response is nil and error contains the following:

> Optional(Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=100 "Protocol error"
>   UserInfo={NSErrorPeerAddressKey={length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes =
>   0x100201bb36fc951f0000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=100,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1})

Comment: If are using URLSession to make the API call, you may need to implement the right delegate methods, specially func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void). Be mindful, this specific delegate has one different variant with URLSessionTaskDelegate.

Comment: ok, i implemented the urlsessiondelegate and it does hit the didReceive callback.  i opted to perform default handling which is i think what it does by default anyway and i still get the same result

Comment: Now that it is clear it is a NSPOSIXErrorDomain, it can be different issue.. Checkout this link.. this has few possible solutions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41461481/error-domain-nsposixerrordomain-code-100-protocol-error

Comment: Yeah, I did catch that thread earlier.  I'm doing a simple get request, so there is no body.  I tried some different content types as a test, but all had the same result :(

Answer (score 1):

Please try to check the HTTP request/response body to see if there are some malformed fields. For example, Content-Length and Content-Type are right or if something is missing.

Comment: Yeah, I saw this suggestion in another thread, but no luck.  Further testing suggests the problem is a combination of swift and the api on IIS 10.  The app works on IIS 8 and fiddler works with IIS 10.  There doesn't seem to be anything in the IIS log files when the error occurs.  I'm pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 0):

Your calls are probably blocked by the App Transport Security. 
Try adding the below items to your .plist file:

`<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>mydomain.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>`

Comment: I had some of these items set already, but tried yours with the same result unfortunately :(