# HTTP2 NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=100 "Protocol error”

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

> Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=100 "Protocol error"
>   UserInfo={_NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask
>   <3EEC44C3-80A3-47B1-A0FD-C5DAD842FAAE>.<2>,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, NSErrorPeerAddressKey={length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes =
>   0x100201bb34d5b9460000000000000000}

I recently switched my server and when I try to get a response am getting this error. I tried changing the header but it didn't work for me. It is working fine when I tried in postman and android

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41461481/error-domain-nsposixerrordomain-code-100-protocol-error